# Update location on background mode do not work when user turn off "Background App Refresh"

Tags: ios, xcode, background, refresh

I want to notify for user to turn on "Background App Refresh" to update location on background mode. How can  I check status of this feature on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable) {

    NSLog(@"Background updates are available for the app.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied)
{
    NSLog(@"The user explicitly disabled background behavior for this app or for the whole system.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted)
{
    NSLog(@"Background updates are unavailable and the user cannot enable them again. For example, this status can occur when parental controls are in effect for the current user.");
}
```

**Method 2**

```
NSArray *backgroundRefreshAuthStatuses = @[@"Restricted",@"Denied",@"Available"];
int brAuth = (int)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus];
NSLog(@"Background refresh authorization status: %@", [backgroundRefreshAuthStatuses objectAtIndex:brAuth]);
```